# Sentences into LTL

Tags: logic

Is this the correct conversion to LTL formula

Lions and zebras never drink at the waterhole together.
(Lions -> Drink) U (zebra -> Drink)

Even if you ask her infinitely often, she will never tell you.
GFask -> ¬Ftell

Once red, the light becomes green eventually after being yellow for a while. FRed -> Xyellow -> Fgreen

Comment: What is LTL?  Do you have a reference?

Comment: Linear Temporal Logic

Comment: I downvoted, because of poor formatting and no context.

Comment: Are you working with propositional LTL or first-order LTL?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with LTL, but I'm looking at the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) page, and do see some issues with your translations:

For your first one: Drink should be a predicate, of which lions and zebras (and other things) are the subject. So, use $Drink(lions)$ or $\exists x (Lion(x) \land Drink(x))$.  Also, using $\cup$ you end up saying that lions are drinking (at the waterhole) until zebras are drinking there ... but it is of course perfectly acceptable for none of them to drink there.

In fact, using $\cup$ seems more appropriate for the third sentence, don't you think? Rather than using thew $\rightarrow$ there.

And for the second one .. when it says 'even if you ask infinitely many times' ... I think it is just emphasizing the point that she never tells. Indeed, by using $G F ask -> ¬F tell$, you are saying that it is true that she never tells *if* she gets asked infinitely many times .. so that does not rule out that she does tell when not asked infitely many times, and I would say that the sentence means that she never tells, whether you ask here one, wtice, never, or infintiely many times. In other words, the whole bit about asking just seemsirrelevant, as it is not a condition of her not telling.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that none of them can drink there?

Comment: Well, you need to symbolize that they can't drink together (or at least, that you can't have a lion and a zebra drinking at the same time).  Saying that is not the same as saying that none of them can drink there at all. You can have   a liion drink there, then a zerba, then two lions, etc tec ... as lonh as they don't drink together it's all ok . which is why I would not use the $\cup$

Comment: So something like (Drink(Lion)∧ ¬ Drink(Zebra)) U (Drink(Zebra)∧ ¬ Drink(lion))

Comment: "Never" means "globally not".  @PhilipD'Souza

Answer (score 0):

I will use the definitions from the wiki article about
[linear temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic).
Similar to propositional logic the sentences of this logic are based on propositional variables.
These are sentences that are true or false and cannot be split into smaller parts using predicates.

> Lions and zebras never drink at the waterhole together.

We use sentences like "a lion drinks at the water hole" ($p$) and "a zebra drinks at the water hole" ($q$)
and do not split these sentences into smaller parts.
The sentence $p$ exactly means "at least one lion drinks at the water hole" and similar holds for $q$.
$$\lnot(p\land q)$$
means that not both a lion and a zebra are drinking at the water hole. This should be true for every point in time so we have
$$\operatorname{G}(\lnot(p\land q))$$

> Even if you ask her infinitely often, she will never tell you.
> The sentence "she will tell you" ($p$) is a proposition that can be true or false.

From my point of view the "even" part of the sentence does not contribute
anything to the logical content of the sentence and can be ignored.
The expression
$$\lnot p$$
means "she does not tell you" and similar to the previous example
we can use the operator $G$ to express that something never will happen:

$$ \operatorname{G}(\lnot p)$$

> Once red, the light becomes green eventually after being yellow for a while.

We have the following elementary sentences: "The light is red"($r$), "the light is yellow" ($y$), "the light is green" ($g$).
Let us try to model this behavior with until-loops.

$$y\operatorname{U}g \tag 1$$
covers paths like

```
y,g,
```

or

```
y, y, g
```

and
$$r\operatorname{U}(y\operatorname{U}g) \tag 2 $$

covers paths like

```
r, y, g
```

or

```
r, r, r, y, y, g,
```

But $(1)$ also describes loops with $0$ iterations like

```
g
```

and also $(2)$ allows

```
y, y, g
r,r,g
g
```

To guarantee at least one iteration in $(1)$ one can use the next operator $X$

$$y \land \operatorname{N}(y \operatorname{U} g)$$

and instead of $(2)$ one uses

$$r \land \operatorname{N}(r \operatorname{U}(y \land \operatorname{N}(y \operatorname{U} g)))$$

But now the first $r$ is the first node of the path. The first $r$ should start anywhere so we use the $\operatorname{F}$ operator

$$\operatorname{F}(r \land \operatorname{N}(r \operatorname{U}(y \land \operatorname{N}(y \operatorname{U} g)))) \tag 3$$

Maybe we should also describe that the light can only have one color, so instead of  $(3)$ we get

$$\operatorname{F}((r\land \lnot y \land \lnot g) \land \operatorname{N}((r\land \lnot y \land \lnot g) \operatorname{U}((\lnot r\land y \land \lnot g) \land \operatorname{N}((\lnot r\land y \land \lnot g) \operatorname{U} (\lnot r\land \lnot y \land g)))))$$